# parts of my rigs neck fly away from the body when I move the upper section of the neck

Tags: rigging, objects

It may be that I overlooked a small problem but when ever I move the upper neck bone on my rig the part that connects both the neck to the head fly out of the body weirdly. I've checked the weight groups and they are only connected to one bone which is the one it should be. Look at photos for a better example and also here is a YT video showing the problem --> https://youtu.be/JVN0XKCJ1xs

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: here is the blender exchange link --> https://blend-exchange.com/b/8opVoLlj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have parented theses pieces twice, once with a parent to > *Bone*, and the second time with the empty groups, that makes these piece move twice the distance they should move. You need to either remove the modifier or deparent from the bone.